# When to capitalize words such as "lake", and when can the whole word be omitted?

Tags: capitalization

Which of the following sentences are correct?

> "He gave two examples of large lakes, Lake Michigan and Lake
>   Superior."
>
> "He gave two examples of large lakes, Michigan and Superior."
>
> "He gave two examples of large Lakes, Michigan and Superior."
>
> "He gave two examples of large lakes, Lakes Michigan and Superior."

This question is primarily about what variants are formally correct, not which one sounds the best.

I think that the question should be valid for several words of the same kind, such as mountain (Mount), figure (Figure), table (Table) and so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You capitalize it when it is used as part of a [proper noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proper_noun). Your first, second, and fourth examples are correct, the third is not.

> He gave two examples of large lakes, Michigan and Superior.

In this example, the *Lake* part in the proper nouns *Lake Michigan* and *Lake Superior* is omitted. The word *lakes* here is not part of a proper noun. So capitalizing it like this,

> He gave two examples of large Lakes, Michigan and Superior.

Is incorrect.

In other cases, the same rule applies: capitalize the words when they appear as part of a proper noun, such as *Mount McKinley* or *Round Table*, but not when they appear as common noun, such as *the tallest mount/mountain* or *coffee table*.

It is also recommended to capitalize references to specific figures, tables, chapters, sections, equations—particularly when they appear with a number or letter identifying them:

> This trend is demonstrated in Figure 5 in Appendix C

But again, not when simply using the common noun.

> This trend is demonstrated in figure below.

Comment: But why is the fourth example correct? I would say that "Lakes" is really a common noun over there so it shouldn't be capitalized.

Comment: @freethinker36 It sounds a little awkward, but it's not entirely uncommon to break up proper nouns when parts of them are repeated, e.g. *He was a fan of Johns Kennedy and Lennon.* In this case the *John* is still part of the proper names, despite pluralization, and should be capitalized. I don't know if this specific phenomenon has a name (it seems to be a form of [ellipsis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis_(linguistics))) so I couldn't find any references.

Answer (score 0):

In your example above, John is a proper noun and would always be capitalized.   However, I agree that "Lakes" should not be capitalized in the fourth example.  "Lakes Michigan" is not a proper noun. Thus, it should read:  "He gave two examples of large lakes, Michigan and Superior."